# Cannot select specific Tab Index to show in Tab Bar Controller, always shows 0th index

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, selectedindex

I have a tab bar controller with four tabs. I want to show the first item at the beginning. With a button click from the first item (view), when it is clicked, I want to show the second tab. How can I do that?

I created a custom `tabbarController` class and tried to give `tabbarindex` like below. I checked at the beginning without a button click but it didn't work. It always loads the first tab bar item.

```
class HTabViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
        self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
       // defineViewController()
    }
}
```

Note : can we show specific tab item with a button click?

Comment: Why you write `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2`? It should be `self.selectedIndex = 2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `self` is the `UITabBarController`, you need to set the `selectedIndex` on `self`, not `self.tabBarController`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    selectedIndex = 2
    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Comment: @Sahil - I deliberately chose not to use `self`. It's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

job done, add `self.selectedIndex = needed_index` at `viewDidLoad()` method